# Can't identify the correct equation for Gabor filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, wavelet

I'm coding a 2D gabor kernel for the purposes of finding the texture orientations in an image. I've been going through two papers and both the authors have presented two different equations for practically the same problem and the code also doesn't matches.

This is the gabor kernel equation in paper 1(page 1, section ||| )..

[image]

This is kernel equation in paper 2 (page 3, equation 1)

[image]

**Questions**: **1**. Does both equations simplify to one result? I tried, but couldn't achieve that simplification.

**2**.This is the code fragment for the filter by author of paper 1.

```
for theta = 90+1:angleInterval:angleRange-angleInterval+1+90
    tmpTheta = (theta - 1)*pi/180;
    for y= -halfKerSize:halfKerSize
        ySinTheta = y*sin(tmpTheta);
        yCosTheta = y*cos(tmpTheta);
        for x=-halfKerSize:halfKerSize
            xCosTheta = x*cos(tmpTheta);
            xSinTheta = x*sin(tmpTheta);
            a = xCosTheta+ySinTheta;
            b = -xSinTheta+yCosTheta;
            oddKernel(y+halfKerSize+1,x+halfKerSize+1,(theta - 1-90)/angleInterval+1) = exp(tmpDelta*(4*a*a+b*b))*(sin(c*a)-exp(-cc*cc/2));
            evenKernel(y+halfKerSize+1,x+halfKerSize+1,(theta - 1-90)/angleInterval+1) = exp(tmpDelta*(4*a*a+b*b))*(cos(c*a)-exp(-cc*cc/2));
        end
    end
end
```

In the code, there is no mention of 'w' as in from w/(sqrt(2*pi)*c.... kernel equation paper 1.

**3**. When simplifying by Euler's expression, exp(iaw) will become cos(aw) + i*sin(aw), so the shouldn't the equations be,

evenKernal = w/(sqrt(2*pi)*c ) * exp( -w^2(4a^2+b^2)/8*c^2 ) *( cos(aw) - exp(-c^2/2))

oddKernel = w/(sqrt(2*pi)*c ) * exp( -w^2(4a^2+b^2)/8*c^2 ) *( sin(aw) ) ?

This is not what I see in the code.

paper 1 : http://web.mit.edu/huikong/www/publications_files/TIP10b.pdf

paper 2 : http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005/uploads/Rasmussen04Grouping.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Equation 1 and Equation 2 are the same. You are on the right track on going about expanding the imaginary term in equation 1.

By clearing each terms independently (and I wish there was tex notation here to go over everything), you should get the following equivalent substitutions:

1) w = 2*pi/lambda

2) lambda = (2*pi)/(sqrt(2*pi*c))

3) sigma = sqrt(c/pi);

Once you see the similarity, parts 2 and 3 of your question should be straightforward to figure out.